# How to optionally include header file

Tags: c, include

In python I can simply do this

```
def func():
    if condition:
        import something
    else:
        import somethingelse
```

Is there any way or standard convention for doing this in standard ANSI C? If it helps, I need print statements to go off when I'm on a computer and for them not to go off when I'm on an embedded system because print functions may not be available for an in-house compiler.

Comment: ANSI C is irrelevant. C is standardised as ISO9899 with the only valid version of 2011. And including files conditionally is likely not the correct way to do what you seem to want. Without these headers, your code will still call the function apparently, but then without the mandatory prototypes. (Whatever you mean with "in-house compiler")

Comment: Well when looking up solutions, I often see solutions that include libraries unique to Linux such as sys\stat.h. I'm sorry that I didn't make that clear. I'm still learning the jargon. Moreover it seems from the answers here I can simply include prototypes with empty functions to mitigate the issue you bring about. In-house means "done within an organization." So it means we built it and it might not include certain things.

Comment: **External** libraries are not related to the C standard. (They need not even be written in C if they comply to the ABI). Prototypes don't define anything. Thus they are not "empty" (whatever that means for e.g. a function which is supposed to return a result). Anyway, it is definitively not just a matter of omitting the declarations, i.e. headers. You might want to make a clean concept before you start thinking about a specific implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define SOME_CONSTANT

#ifdef SOME_CONSTANT

#include<header.h>

#else

#include<otherheader.h>

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

This is typically accomplished with conditional compilation.

```
#if EMBEDDED == 1
#define print_xxx(...) (void)0
#endif
```

Whether or not `EMBEDDED` is defined with the proper value is determined at build time. At that time, depending on platform, the compilation flags can reflect what kind of platform is being targeted.